# Heart rate(BPM) calculation from .wav file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio, audio-processing

I have a digital stethoscope with me I can record the Human heart sound easily with an Android phone and it is clear, I can listen lub-dub(s1-S2) clearly from the recorded file.

I want to calculate the Heart rate of recorded audio, is there any way to calculate BPM from audio file?

I have written application for Android in Kotlin and some parts in java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic. But I recommend [Noise](https://github.com/paramsen/noise) for working with FFTs. You'll have to read up on the math of FFTs to know what you're looking for to find the heat beats.

Comment: Unless the heart is oscillating (in which case have a word with your patient) I’m not sure a Fourier transform will tell you much. For bpm you’ll want to detect peaks and find the distance between them. With a wav you‘ll know sample rate so can deduce the duration between peaks. You’ll probably want to have a moving average window of readings for some stability. If this is for medical purposes, consult a University, not the internet. In any case this is sadly not a question suited for SO.

Comment: All sound oscillates. An FFT can be used to filter out the frequencies of sound and general noise you don't care about so you have a clearer signal to sample for peaks. Granted, it might not be necessary. I've never worked with heartbeat audio.

Comment: Can you upload one or a few audio files?

Comment: @JonNordby I can't share that files with you

Answer (score 2):

First, obtain the stream of PCM values for the data (for example floats ranging from -1 to 1 or maybe shorts from -32768 to 32767 if your data is 16-bit). I'm assuming signed PCM.

Second, apply an RMS (root-mean-square) function to the data to get the relative power of the volume over the course of the data, and look for the peaks. I'm assuming that each "thump" will be a point of relative loudness and that the audio between "thumps" will have less volume.

Third, count the number of frames between the peaks. Using your sample rate, you can derive a time value from that.

IDK the specifics of how Android/Kotlin systems provide access to the PCM. Most likely it will be in the form of a byte stream that is encoded according to the audio format. For example, mono, 44100 fps, 16-bits, little-endian. Using Java, a `TargetDataLine` might be involved.

SO has questions that explain how to convert the bytes to PCM.

SO also has questions about how to apply an RMS function to the PCM. There is some aggregation involved, as it involves calculating a moving average.

I don't know if frequency analysis tool would be helpful. The frequency of the heartbeat is very low, like 1 or 2 per second. We can't even hear frequencies below 20 per second. But there ARE likely tools that work in that low a frequency range.